# Data eliminated while fetching from view in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am running following query

```
insert  into [tbl_Readership] -- Record count 7812940

select * from [vw_PortalReadership] -- Record count 7812985
```

while running this query I am getting following warning:

> Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

And some of my data i am loosing. Any suggestion how to track those records which are eliminated.

Comment: what is the `vw_PortalReadership` defintion

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard ANSI warning, and an expected behavior.

Whichever columns are being aggregated in your view are able to have `null` values in your table, and at least one of them does.

Once you have the name/s of the column/s in the view being aggregated, you can see which ones are `null` in your table with:

```
select *
from [tbl_Readership]
where [aggregated_column_name] is null
```